# Ways of applying image effects on Python3 in the same window

Tags: atom-editor, python-3.7

So the thing is that I started with python not so long ago and I'm trying to get some code to work. Basically what I'm trying to to is create a window that contains an image and when some buttons are pressed, the image changes (size, blur, etc...) Some of the problems I'm encountering is the blur only taking effect once and the resize effect creating another image above the bigger/smaller one and the latter one not being deleted. is there a way to make all this to work? Thank you in advance.
I may have used too many lines of code, I'm fully aware of it as I still don't have enough knowledge :).

```
import tkinter
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk

def blur_image():
    print("Blur")
    global photo_blur
    global cv_img_blur

    cv_img_blur = cv2.blur(cv_img, (3, 3))
    photo_blur = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv_img_blur))
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo_blur, anchor=tkinter.NW)

def reduce_image():
    print("Reduced")
    global photo_reduce
    global cv_img_reduce

cv_img_reduce = cv2.resize(cv_img, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
photo_reduce = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv_img_reduce))
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo_reduce, anchor=tkinter.NW)

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Project")

cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("hqdefault.jpg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

height, width, no_channels = cv_img.shape

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()

photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv_img))

canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)

btn_blur=tkinter.Button(window, text="Blur", width=50, command=blur_image)
btn_blur.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True)

btn_reduce=tkinter.Button(window, text="Reduce", width=50, command=reduce_image)
btn_reduce.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
import tkinter
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk

blur_status = (3, 3)

def blur_image():

    print("Blur")
    global photo_blur, cv_img_blur, image, blur_status

    cv_img_blur = cv2.blur(cv_img, blur_status)
    photo_blur = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv_img_blur))
    canvas.delete(image)
    image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo_blur, anchor=tkinter.NW)

    n1, n2 = blur_status
    blur_status = (n1 + 1, n2 + 2)


def reduce_image():

    print("Reduced")
    global photo_reduce, cv_img_reduce, image

    cv_img_reduce = cv2.resize(cv_img, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    photo_reduce = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv_img_reduce))
    canvas.delete(image)
    image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo_reduce, anchor=tkinter.NW)


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Project")

cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("home.png"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

height, width, no_channels = cv_img.shape

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()

photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv_img))

image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)

btn_blur = tkinter.Button(window, text="Blur", width=50, command=blur_image)
btn_blur.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True)

btn_reduce = tkinter.Button(window, text="Reduce", width=50, command=reduce_image)
btn_reduce.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True)

window.mainloop()
```

In realtà le funzioni che hai chiamato sono andate a sovrapporre le immagini perché ne hanno sempre create di nuove senza modificare quelle precedentemente create, quindi prima di creare una nuova imagine bisogna eliminare quella vecchia. La sfocatura sembrava funzionare solo la prima volta perché i valori non aumentavano perché erano sempre impostati su (3, 3), se vuoi che "lavori più volte" devi aumentare i valori each time that you call the function

Comment: Oh, this worked wonders. Thank you! I'll try read everything to see if I get the drift of it.